# Chef: Load Attributes from encrypted databag in json role

Tags: chef, json

I'm want to use the postfix cookbook for chef. The sasl password is expected to be in an attribute. So usually you would do this:

```
"default_attributes": {
  "postfix": {
    "sasl": {
      "smtp_sasl_passwd": "somepassword"
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is: I don't want to have the password in the repository in plain text. So I put it in an encrypted data bag. Now I want to access it. This can be done with this:

```
Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("passwords", "postfix")['password']
```

The problem: This only works in a .rb file, but my role is in json; all my roles are in json! I don't want to change that just for this purpose. Does anybody have an idea what to do here? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting your roles to the Ruby DSL would not help here - they are converted to JSON before being uploaded to the Chef server, and it is the JSON version that is loaded by chef-client.  The same is true of environments.

In other words, there's no way to load a databag (encrypted or otherwise) from a role or environment.  You'll need to put that kind of logic into a cookbook recipe.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Figured that out myself in the meantime and wrote a wrapper cookbook, that works well!